# crash on generating random number in eclipde

Tags: java, android, eclipse

```
package com.example.gameofguessing;

import java.util.Random;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Screen extends Activity {
    String lowerlimit1;
    String upperlimit1;
    int ulimit;
    int llimit;
    int count;
    Intent nextscreen = Screen.this.getIntent();

    {
        lowerlimit1 = nextscreen.getStringExtra("llimit");
        upperlimit1 = nextscreen.getStringExtra("ulimit");
        // limit.setText(lowerlimit1);
        llimit = Integer.parseInt(lowerlimit1);
        ulimit = Integer.parseInt(upperlimit1);
    }
    Random random = new Random();
    int randumnum = random.nextInt(ulimit - llimit + 1) + llimit;
    Button go;
    TextView limit;
    EditText number;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen);

        number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        go = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        limit = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        go.setOnClickListener(input);

    }
    OnClickListener input = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(llimit <= randumnum) {
                limit.setText("Too low");
                number.setText("");
                count = +1;

            }
            else if(llimit >= randumnum) {
                limit.setText("Too high");
                number.setText("");
                count = +1;
            }
            else {
                count = +1;
                limit.setText("You got the number after" + count + "tries");
            }
        }
    };
}
```

This is what i have so far and I don't get why my emulator keeps on crashing. Its something to do with the random number or the intent for sure.
Please help

Comment: This is a professional forum, not a chat room. Just write a sensible 'Please Help'.

Comment: Not part of your problem, but maybe a problem: You are setting your count-field to the positive value of 1 (+1). I think, you want to increment it - `count += 1` or simple `count++`

Comment: Read the [training](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html) documentation closely. You can not put code in your class without a method. (there is no Intent to get, it's only available from within `onCreate` and later)

Answer (score 2):

Try this. The problem is that you're calling `getIntent()` before the `onCreate` method has executed. Therefore the received intent hasn't been initialised and loaded yet so you get a `NullPointerException`.

```
 package com.example.gameofguessing;

import java.util.Random;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Screen extends Activity {
    String lowerlimit1;
    String upperlimit1;
    int ulimit;
    int llimit;
    int count;
    int randumnum
    Button go;
    TextView limit;
    EditText number;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen);

        number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        go = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        limit = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        go.setOnClickListener(input);

        Intent nextscreen = Screen.this.getIntent();
        lowerlimit1 = nextscreen.getStringExtra("llimit");
        upperlimit1 = nextscreen.getStringExtra("ulimit");
        // limit.setText(lowerlimit1);
        llimit = Integer.parseInt(lowerlimit1);
        ulimit = Integer.parseInt(upperlimit1);

        Random random = new Random();
        randumnum = random.nextInt(ulimit - llimit + 1) + llimit;

        }
OnClickListener input = new OnClickListener() {     
        @Override   
        public void onClick(View v) {   



            if (llimit <= randumnum) {
                limit.setText("Too low");
                number.setText("");
                count = +1;

            } else if (llimit >= randumnum) {
                limit.setText("Too high");
                number.setText("");
                count = +1;
            } else {
                count = +1;
                limit.setText("You got the number after" + count + "tries");

            }

        }

    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int randumnum = random.nextInt(ulimit - llimit + 1) + llimit;
```

Put this line inside `onCreate()` or any one of your method. Because a class should contain only variables and methods, All definitions should be inside a method. This is a definition. Should go inside a method.